# Using OleDB to read excel file in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am building a program to read excel file into dataGridView.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace pro1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sConnecStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=c:\\Copy_of_Acute_HCV_2008.xls" + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"; 
            OleDbConnection conObj = new OleDbConnection(sConnecStr);
            conObj.Open();
            OleDbCommand sqlCommand  = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",conObj);
            OleDbDataAdapter adaObj = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adaObj.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
            DataSet setObj = new DataSet();
            adaObj.Fill(setObj);
            conObj.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = setObj.Tables[0];

            dataGridView1.Refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

The program runs fine when i use a small excel file but when i use a big excel file it gives me this error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Sheet1$' is
>   not a valid name.  Make sure that it
>   does not include invalid characters or
>   punctuation and that it is not too
>   long.

thanks

edit: i always use .xls files not .xlsx

Comment: Is there a worksheet named "Sheet1" in the big Excel file?

Comment: you are right , how didn't i see that  thanks

Comment: use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ((txtFilePath.HasFile))
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string query = null;
            string connString = "";
            string strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
            string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(txtFilePath.FileName).ToString().ToLower();

            if (strFileType == ".xls" || strFileType == ".xlsx")
            {
                txtFilePath.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedExcel/" + strFileName + strFileType));
            }

            string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedExcel/" + strFileName + strFileType);
            if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
            string SpreadSheetName = "";
            DataTable ExcelSheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

            SpreadSheetName = ExcelSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            query = "SELECT * FROM [" + SpreadSheetName + "]";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tab1");
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: This is poorly formatted and doesn't give any sort of explanation, just code (which also doesn't seem to be based on the code in the question but rather some other project). I see that you are a new user, so try to make your coming answers more descriptive and try to really help the person asking instead of just giving large chunks of code.

Comment: @Geeta Please flesh out your answer. Give out some explanations as to why this code helps the OP.

Comment: Nice Its Working Good Thanks