# Excel Reader (set general variable for sheet1$)

Tags: c#, excel

In reference to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052987/using-oledb-to-read-excel-file-in-c) I would like to know if there is any way i can read from an excel file with out having to set the application to read from, say `Sheet1` for example `OleDbCommand sqlCommand  = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",conObj);` but instead use some kind of variable  that denotes the first sheet

Comment: `strsql = "SELECT * FROM [" & Worksheets(1).Name & "$]"` (from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0658347b-33dd-4074-b1cd-630ab9556a9c/select-index-instead-of-sheet1-to-read-data?forum=exceldev))

Comment: I've checked out that site, and ran the above code you provided but it says `worksheets` does not exist in the current context

Comment: I guess you would have to use the appropriate worksheets collection from the rest of your code, you know, all the stuff that's missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use String interpolation to inject your variable into the db command:

```
var sheetNo = "Sheet1$";
OleDbCommand sqlCommand  = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{sheetNo}]",conObj);
```

Comment: I Tried The string interpolation, but received this error **Additional information: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If '1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.**

Comment: This is what i did `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{1}]", con);`

Comment: @Jeremy22 You did something different to what the answer suggested, and it didn't work. What if you try doing what the answer suggested? Does **that** work?

Comment: @Jeremy22 you cannot name your variables starting with a number in c#, could you try naming your variable sheetNo and let me know what the result is?

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness **Additional information: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'SheetNo'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'SheetNo' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator..**

Comment: @Jeremy22 it looks like for some reason string interpolation isn't working for you, Could you try the following: `var sheetNo = "Sheet1$";
string.Format("OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetNo),conObj);` If this doesn't work could you please let me know what version of the .NET framework you are using? Or if you are using .NET Core?

Comment: Is it the same bug?

Answer (score 0):

I put the sheet names in a combo box and after selecting a sheet you can load the grid.

```
private void GetSheets()
        {
            string strFileName = @"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\TestImport.xlsx";
            string strCon = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";
            DataTable dt;
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {
                cn.Open();
                dt = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            }
            string[] exSheets = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            { 
                //Get the sheet name from the DataTable
                string strSheetName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                exSheets[i] = strSheetName;
                i ++;
            }
            cboSheets.Items.AddRange(exSheets);
        }

        private void btnFillGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string strFileName = @"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\TestImport.xlsx";
            string  strCon  = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"Select * From [{cboSheets.Text}];", cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(dr);
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```